# ```sudo apt --fix-broken install``` error: ```Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```

Tags: apt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to use `katoolin` to install Kali tools. When trying to install the tools, I keep getting the following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fragroute : Depends: libdumbnet1 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libevent-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable) but it is not going to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad (= 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2)
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.14.4) but 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
                             Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.14.4) but 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                             Depends: libx264-155 but it is not going to be installed
 sessioninstaller : Depends: aptdaemon (>= 0.30) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

As said in the error, I tried running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` but encountered the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.14.4-1+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0', which is also in package libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4
dpkg: regarding .../libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.14.4-2_amd64.deb containing libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 conflicts with libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (<< 1.13.1)
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 (version 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.14.4-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.14.4-1+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.14.4-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` returns the following:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 depends on libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.14.4); however:
  Version of libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 on system is 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3.
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 depends on libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.14.4); however:
  Version of libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 on system is 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1.
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 depends on libx264-155; however:
  Package libx264-155 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
ldconfig: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64
```

I've also tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 gcc-5-multilib gcc-multilib

sudo apt autoremove -f

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get update
```

but `sudo apt --fix-broken install` still doesn't word

How should I get `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and the rest of `katoolin` to work?

Comment: I believe the error I got is different, so no?

Comment: You hosed your package management by updating the software with the Kali linux repositories that Katoolin added to your software sources enabled. Katoolin often has to effect of a jackhammer on package management in Ubuntu.